# Build turf.js with Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, turfjs

I am trying to build a recent copy of [turf-buffer](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-buffer) which is a module of [turf.js](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf). I ran `npm install turf-buffer` and then `browserify turf-buffer/index.js > turf.js`. However, upon including the resulting turf.js in the html file (it is definitely there) and calling `var buffered = turf.buffer(originalData, buf, 'meters');` I get the message `turf is not defined`. I have also tried `turfjs.xxx`, `turf-buffer.xxx` and various other combinations. If I try turfxxxx.yyy then I still get `turf is not defined` which suggests a fundamental turf object is missing. I presume this is a problem with the browserify build. Is there a flag I need to give to browserify or could it be a lack of package-specific instructions?

Comment: Can you show us where you are trying to access `turf` and where the error message is originating from?

Comment: Thanks. Have added command into answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it - I needed to specify an entry point (not sure if that is the right term) by using -s, so the final command was `browserify turf-buffer/index.js -s turf.buffer > turf.js`.